# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react3.default.PropTypes.bool')

Tags: react-native

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aUmF.png)

Error occurs even if I just import the component without using it

I just made an import in my .js file `"import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper2';"`
https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-swiper2/blob/master/src/Swiper.android.js#L102

Answer (score 1):

I would start by using Chrome Developer Tools to debug your issue.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools

You can step through your code until you get to the error. Something is being evaluate but is undefined.

Comment: Yeah. I debugged through. It says PropTypes.bool is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is because 'PropTypes' was removed from React post version 15.5.

**"React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead."**

To fix this :

1. Install the library
   `sudo npm install prop-types --save`
2. In you js file,
   `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`
3. Instead of using PropTypes from React, use the PropTypes imported from 'prop-types'

   i.e. Replace all `React.PropTypes` with `PropTypes`

Answer (score 0):

According to the React V15.5.0, PropTypes is not imported from react native, but from 'prop-types' -> `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` and change `React.PropTypes` to `PropTypes`. https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html